# Opening an Attached text File from an Email

Tags: android, android-intent

What I want to do seems kind of simple however I am missing some detail somewhere.My goal is to create an application that can open a text file attached to an email.  I have sent myself an email with a text file attached to it with a file extension of TRE. I created an android application with an intent specified in the manifest that will start the app. It does this fine. I have code in the OnCreate function to read data from the intent to get the file name. This is where it gets weird. When I open the email, it saves the attachement to temp-10.tre. However when the app opens it says the filename is /4/4731/RAW. Of course when I try to open this file it says it can not open it. I suspect this filename is not correct.

Below is the manifest code:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TREViewerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" /> 
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.tre" />     
        </intent-filter> 

    </activity>
</application>
```

Below is the code I use to get the filename:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    strFilename = "Not set";
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent != null)
    {
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        if(uri != null)
        {
            strFilename = intent.getData().getPath();
            readFile();             
        }
    }
```

Below is what I use to open the file:

```
private void readFile()
{
    try
    {
        FileInputStream inFile = new FileInputStream(strFilename);
        inFile.close();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File opened ok",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString() +   e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
    }

}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?